# Map and operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I know that this may be a silly question but i am new to STL.I have the following problem.Got a base class witch is abstract,got a derived class ( CSubject ) , and i am trying to declare a map < CStudent,double> and when i try to make a setter for that map i get the following error "no operator "=" matches these operands" i have declared operator '=' in the CSubject class.If you could help me i would be very thankful.Thanks in advice !

```
class CStudent
{
    ....    
    CStudent& operator = (const CStudent& rhs)
    {
        this->m_szFakultetNumber = rhs.m_szFakultetNumber;
        this->m_szSpecialnost = rhs.m_szSpecialnost;
        this->SetName(rhs.GetName());
        this->SetEGN(rhs.GetEGN());

        return *this;
    }
};

class CSubject
{
    private:
        std::string m_szDisciplineName;
        std::map<std::unique_ptr<CStudent>, unsigned>m_mapOStudentGrade;

    public:

        void SetDisciplineName(const std::string szDisciplineName)
        {
            m_szDisciplineName = szDisciplineName;
        }

        void SetStudentGrade(const std::map<std::unique_ptr<CStudent>, double>mapOStudentGrade)
        {
            m_mapOStudentGrade = mapOStudentGrade;
        }

};
```

Comment: From what I see CSubject is not derived from CStudent.

Comment: Specialnost. :-)

Major, perhaps?

Comment: Additionally, to be able to use in a map, you yet need a comparator; you could implement one explicitly, which would then be passed to the map as template parameter, you might specialise `std::less` for CStudent, or, **easiest**, implement `operator<` for CStudent (which would then be called by default `std::less`...).

Comment: @Aconcagua `std::unique_ptr` has an [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp). It doesn't compare the pointee, so it's not great in this context

Comment: @Caleth Noticed already, wanted to refine in another comment; would have been required for `std::map<CStudent, ...>`. Smart pointers in the given case will rather be hindering anyway, at least  `std::unique_ptr` - what, if a student takes part in more than one subject?

Comment: @Aconcagua *owning* pointers are probably inappropriate here, but we don't know if there is a more appropriate owner in OP's model

Comment: @Caleth At least, `std::shared_ptr` would allow to one and the same student taking part in more than one subject...

Answer (score 3):

`std::map<std::unique_ptr<CStudent>, unsigned>` is a different, unrelated type to `std::map<std::unique_ptr<CStudent>, double>`. You need to pick one of those, and stick with it.

Note that `const` qualifying the `mapOStudentGrade` parameter does nothing here, apart from preventing you from move assigning `m_mapOStudentGrade`. You will need to do that, because your `std::unique_ptr<CStudent>` are not copyable.

Note also that you will not be able to lookup items in your map, because no external `std::unique_ptr<CStudent>`s will ever be equivalent to the ones in the map. Your example doesn't contain any attempts at this, so it may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Shoudn't the parameter be an rvalue reference as well? How would we move the map into the parameter otherwise?

Comment: @Aconcagua no, it can just be a (non-reference) l-value parameter.